# Applying directly and through recruiter for different jobs same company

Tags: hiring-process, recruitment, job-offer

I applied online for an analyst position at a bank but received no feedback except an automatic reply that the application was received. A few weeks later I was contacted by a recruitment agency about a different role in the same company, I have since interviewed for that role and been successful, and are now proceeding to the offer stage and signing the contracts. Would by previous application affect the offer, since they had my resume prior to being introduced by the recruiter? Or should I not say anything because they are different roles? Will the company HR even find out?

Answer (score 2):

I dont see this as being an issue. I work for a large corporation and all the paperwork we have, including online resumes and personal application requests, it would be highly unlikely for them to ever create any sort of issue with your first resume. From personal experience I think it will get lost in the shuffle.

Answer (score 1):

The recruiter must be using a different avenue. I'd say that your recruiter earned their money since whoever got your resume at the bank is sitting on that resume.

Make sure that you tell the recruiter what you did earlier so that everything is above board and in the clear.

Answer (score 1):

Could the previous application matter if brought to their attention?

**TLDR;**

It could matter, but it's not in your interest to bring it up, nor would it be expected of you to raise it.

**Reason it could matter #1: Employer Interview notes**

Your previous analyst application would have some notes associated with the applicaiton. Given that you never heard back, it's very likely that those notes would be very uninteresting (e.g. "Candidate bulk rejected as a suitable candidate was hired"), but they could have negative/critical commentary (e.g. "candidate unsuitable because of X"). Given that you never received an interview the likelihood of those notes affecting your newly accepted offer is very low. But either way, it's not really in your interest to highlight this to HR. They certainly wouldn't expect you to anyway.

**Reason it could matter #2: Recruiter contracts**

The employer signs a contract with the recruiter before engaging them. Usually (but not always) these agreements have clauses that prevent fees being payable to the recruiter if the employer was already aware of the candidate, usually within some period of time.

In this case if the employer were to notify the recruiter that they were aware of your application, the recruiter might not be paid. At this point the recruiter might stop supporting the candidate since they're no longer incentivised to do so, but you've already receved the offer so that doesn't affect you.